# How to stretch a CheckBox while maintaining everything aligned

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, custom-controls

I'm writing a custom checkable ListBox and the items must be checked when an item is selected. The easiest approach I could come up with is to increase the CheckBox height/width (size) to cover the whole ListBoxItem area, however I couldn't manage to vertically align the square and its text, eg:

[image]

The red text is somewhat the desired alignment, given its whole area (blue rectangle). What's necessary to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everybody's always gotta try and over-complicate things :)

Try `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"`.

Comment: Oh my godness!!! I've been struggling with this for so long for such a simple answer! You're the man!